# ReScript, TypeScript: Cannot find module '@rescript/react/src/ReactDOM.gen' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reason, rescript

I am gradually rewriting an application with React to TypeScript into ReScript.
I've already implemented few components in ReScript, but this is the first one, where I use `ReactDOM.Style.t` as property to my component.

Here is my minimized component code:

```
@genType
@react.component
let make = (~sx: option<ReactDOM.Style.t>=?) => {
  <div></div>
}
```

ReScript compiles fine (except a warning that `sx` is not used, but we can ignore it).

I have the following `bs.js` generated, which seems to be fine:

```js
// Generated by ReScript, PLEASE EDIT WITH CARE

import * as React from "react";

function InhypedIcon(Props) {
  return React.createElement("div", undefined);
}

var make = InhypedIcon;

export {
  make ,

}
/* react Not a pure module */
```

And the following corresponding `.gen.tsx` file, which causes the problem:

```
/* TypeScript file generated from InhypedIcon.res by genType. */
/* eslint-disable import/first */


import * as React from 'react';

// @ts-ignore: Implicit any on import
import * as InhypedIconBS__Es6Import from './InhypedIcon.bs';
const InhypedIconBS: any = InhypedIconBS__Es6Import;

import type {Style_t as ReactDOM_Style_t} from '@rescript/react/src/ReactDOM.gen';

// tslint:disable-next-line:interface-over-type-literal
export type Props = { readonly sx?: ReactDOM_Style_t };

export const make: React.ComponentType<{ readonly sx?: ReactDOM_Style_t }> = InhypedIconBS.make;
```

This does not compile, I am getting TypeScript error:

```
TypeScript error in /app/src/icons/InhypedIcon.gen.tsx(11,48):
Cannot find module '@rescript/react/src/ReactDOM.gen' or its corresponding type declarations.  TS2307

     9 | const InhypedIconBS: any = InhypedIconBS__Es6Import;
    10 |
  > 11 | import type {Style_t as ReactDOM_Style_t} from '@rescript/react/src/ReactDOM.gen';
       |                                                ^
    12 |
    13 | // tslint:disable-next-line:interface-over-type-literal
    14 | export type Props = { readonly sx?: ReactDOM_Style_t };
```

I do understand, that TS can not find `rescript/react/src/ReactDOM.gen`, however I am not really know why.
Any ideas how this can be fixed?

My package versions:

```
node: v16.6.2

"typescript": "^4.1.2"
"rescript": "^9.1.4"
"@rescript/react": "^0.10.3"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to provide reproducible example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because rescript bindings to react do not come with GenType, so in case you want it, you have to type it yourself (cf [the docs to import types](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/gentype/latest/usage#export-and-import-types)):

```
@genType.import(("react", "CSSProperties"))
type reactStyle = ReactDOM.Style.t

@genType
@react.component
let make = (~sx: option<reactStyle>=?) => {
  <div></div>
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Is this documented ?

Comment: I just added a link to the docs about type import, but it's true they only document opaque types but it also works when aliasing a type.